# Load data before or after navigating to the uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, user-experience

I am developing an app which contains of many chained viewcontrollers, but i am loading a specific data to each of them based on the inputs from previous viewcontroller.

If I push new view controller and do data request when in it's viewDidLoad, user may see a blank screen, if there's slow internet connection. On the other hand, if i load data when user touched "next" button, and wait for the response before pushing next view controller. But in this case user might think that app laggs. 
What's your opinion for this situation ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a loading overlay is your one stop solution for this. In my project, I've added a custom full screen overlay which entertains user while data is being loaded instead of blank or empty screen.

Take a look at [this link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress) for few cool loading overlays. And [here](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is the sample project of loading overlays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So am i right, that i should navigate user to the next view controller, and show a loader, instead of waiting it to load on the current view controller?

Comment: Yes, thats how you should implement!